# Symfony2 framework.ide setting on Windows

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently trying to learn Symfony2 and trying to set it up. There is a framework.ide setting within Symfony2 that allows for opening the controller and action in your IDE.

I am currently using PhpStorm together with Remote Call. I have figured out how to get this working on a Linux environment, however, in Windows this doesn't want to work due to Windows using backwards slashes (which JavaScript seems to escape).

My current config looks like this:
**config_dev.yml**

```
framework:
    ide: 'javascript: var r = new XMLHttpRequest; r.open("get", "http://localhost:8091?message=%%f:%%l");r.send()'
```

This makes the debugger's action name link to:

```
javascript: var r = new XMLHttpRequest; r.open("get", "http://localhost:8091?message=C:\Users\Hosh\vhosts\symfony\src\Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\WelcomeController.php:9");r.send()
```

Which is nice and all, however, JavaScript seems to see the file path as:

```
javascript: var r = new XMLHttpRequest; r.open("get", "http://localhost:8091?message=C:UsersUservhostssymfonysrcAcmeDemoBundleControllerWelcomeController.php:9");r.send()
```

My current solution is by overriding the template `WebProfileBundle:Collector:request.html.twig` and manually running the link through a replace filter so that:

```
 7.            <span class="sf-toolbar-info-class sf-toolbar-info-with-next-pointer">{{ collector.controller.class|abbr_class }}</span>
 8.            <span class="sf-toolbar-info-method" onclick="{% if link %}window.location='{{link}}';window.event.stopPropagation();return false;{% endif %}">
 9.                {{ collector.controller.method }}
10.            </span>
```

becomes:

```
 7.            <span class="sf-toolbar-info-class sf-toolbar-info-with-next-pointer">{{ collector.controller.class|abbr_class }}</span>
 8.             <span class="sf-toolbar-info-method" onclick="{% if link %}{{ link|replace({'\\': '/'}) }}{% endif %}">
 9.                {{ collector.controller.method }}
10.            </span>
```

Is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way and you don't even need the Remote Call plugin. You can register a custom protocol handler in Windows Registry and edit the framework.ide to use that handler.

See this: https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol